# Configuring multiple IPs for amazon EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian

I need a separate ip addresses for my two sites, so I'm manually configuring Amazon Web services to have 2 public ips with an instance. I've set up 2 elastic ips that are pointed to 2 private ips and they are all under a single network interface.

What manual changes do I need to make to OS (Debian 7) to make the secondary elastic (public) ip to work?

This is what /etc/network/interfaces looks like right now:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

P.S. There does not seem to be a ec2-net-utils package for debian, so I'm doing it manually, thus also learning how networking works.

Comment: You may try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448107/aws-second-elastic-ip-not-working-after-correct-dhclient-results/51426529#51426529

Comment: How did you make this work with the secondary interface?

Answer (score -2):

As per my knowledge, You cannot setup multiple IP in amazon Ec2. You need to assign the IP to each instance and normal EC2 will allow only one IP per instance.

And you can configure two website with one public IP and it will not create any performance issue. If you are particular about two public IP, you can check with VPC in amazon WS

Comment: -1 this is false. You can attach multiple NICs to an instance, and multiple Elastic IPs to each NIC. On the t2.micro you can have a max of 4 IPs per instance.